redimensionar texto y botón
Estoy practicando con CSS a redimensionar un par de botones y lo que no consigo es que se redimensiones el texto en relación al tamaño del botón.
.boton{
    padding: 2%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 1% 1%;
    margin-left: 2vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}


El texto no va a cambiar nunca, le has dicho que su tamaño es 1rem (16px para un tamaño de fuente NORMAL en la configuración del navegador). No es un tamaño que varíe como el %. Por cierto, tienes padding 2% y abajo padding 1% 1%, elige uno de los dos, pues tal cual lo tienes te sobra la línea del padding: 2%;. Si quieres que la fuente varíe en función del tamaño, usa un tamaño de fuente que sea variable, no fijo. La otra opción sería usar un container query para hacerlo tú mismo "a mano"... hay muchas maneras de hacer las cosas, pero hay que hacerlas. CSS no hace magia :)

Lo mas cercano a eso es tener tamaños basado en el viewport width, es decir, usando vw, por ejemplo.


a {
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding: 1vw 2vw;
  background-color: #A92121;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
<a href="#">Hola Mundo</a>



En este caso, vw hace referencia al tamaño de la pantalla o viewport width, de modo que el botón y el texto reescalan con la pantalla, pero aun deben ser configurados los tamaños a mano.
